# Returning a subclass as type of superclass

Tags: typescript

I'm working with TypeScript and React; I want extend a base component and then have a function that returns one of many subclasses.

For example:

```
class SuperComponent extends React.Component { }

class SubComponent extends SuperComponent { }

function get(): SuperComponent {
    return SubComponent;
}
```

However, TypeScript throws the following error:

> error TS2322: Type 'typeof SubComponent' is not assignable to type 'SuperComponent'.
>     Property 'setState' is missing in type 'typeof SubComponent'.

Seems like this isn't React-specific, because I can reproduce it pretty easily:

```
class BaseClass {
    myMethod() {}
}

class SuperClass extends BaseClass {}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {}

function get2(): SuperClass {
    return SubClass;
}
```

> error TS2322: Type 'typeof SubClass' is not assignable to type 'SuperClass'.
>     Property 'myMethod' is missing in type 'typeof SubClass'.

This should be possible, right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually create an instance of your component:

```
class SuperComponent extends React.Component { }

class SubComponent extends SuperComponent { }

function get(): SuperComponent {
    return new SubComponent({});
}
```

If you want to return the type of the component then you need to use `typeof SuperComponent` as the return type:

```
function get(): typeof SuperComponent {
    return SubComponent;
}
```